# Continuously count up then count back down?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is more an algorithm question but in a C++ language but I’m trying to wrap my head around how I would count up to 10 then back down to 0 in a continuous fashion.

0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1..

I’m guessing it would have to be two nested loops and maybe a bool value to determine which way it’s counting, up or down?

My attempt to this is the following but I'm not sure if there is a more optimized way to go about this:

```
int count = 0;
int max = 10;
int min = 0;
bool incrementing = true;

while (true) {

    printf("%d-", count);

    if (incrementing) {
        count += 1;
        if (count == max) {
            incrementing = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        count -= 1;
        if (count == min) {
            incrementing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it could take 3 loops - one for up, one for down, one to repeat

Comment: there are ways you could do it with one too

Comment: @DanielA.White I like the idea - but probably too refined for OPs purpose.

Comment: Recursion would work very nicely as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a task that'd be easily solvable using very simple loops.

Comment: How far did you get? Can you make a program which count 0 to 10? Can you make  a program which counts 10 to 0? Can you make a program which does both? Whatever you can do, please show it. If you cannot do any of that, then you are asking for a basic turorial, which is off-topic.

Comment: If the question only mentions C++ and only is about C++, then please do not additionally tag an unrelated language.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good idea there. Give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick-n-dirty; One loop; Repeats infinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int delta = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 10;
    int min = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d-",count);
        count += delta;
        if(count == min || count == max) delta = -delta;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-1-2-3-4-5-6
```

Comment: Challenge: Do it with only variables `min`, `max` and `count`. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch added example without delta in initial question but with a bool, which is less memory due to 3 ints + 1 bool vs 4 ints